# Categories of a category_group won’t show

Tags: categories, mysql, category-group

I have a strange thing in EE 2.8.1.  I want to show a list of all categories in category_group=“1” but nothing won’t show up.

I have 3 category groups

- ID 1 - with 105 categories, top & sub level, Channel = "Producten"
- ID 2 - with 2 categories, Channel = "Nieuws"
- ID 3 - with 1 categorie, Channel = "Producten"

When i use for example:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="producten" dynamic="no"}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}

{exp:channel:categories category_group="2" dynamic="no"}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}

{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" dynamic="no"}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

- Example One: I just get the one category from ID 3 and nothing from ID 1
- Example Two: Just works great, nothing special
- Example Three: Nothing happend, but why?

So i don’t see what can be the problem, anybody else have a idea? Looks like EE does not see Group 1.

Comment: Have you try without dynamic="0" ?

Comment: I did now but no result
 
Channel="Producten"
Test
----
ID2
Nieuws
Projecten
----
ID1
----
ID0
Nieuws
Projecten
Test

Comment: And also dynamic="0" doesn't change anything. Really strange, looks like the database doesn't exists.

Comment: Sorry I mean don't use dynamic="no", just try like that:{exp:channel:categories category_group="1"}

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the channel parameter, and you can leave out dynamic="no" because that's not a parameter for this tag.

If specifying the channel parameter does not work,try adding the following parameters: 
status="not closed" 
show_future_entries="yes"
show_expired="yes"

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" status="not closed" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

If the tag then outputs your categories, the reason they were not showing up is because the entries with those categories did not meet the default conditions i.e. entries with a status of open with an entry date in the past which have not expired. So you can then adjust the parameters to suit your particular entries e.g. omit the show_expired parameter if you don't want categories with only expired entries included.

You can review all the parameters for the channel categories tag at http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/categories.html#parameters

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i understand what you mean with the parameters. But no luck with it. Still nothing shows up with your code. When i change the ID1 to a ID2 i get those categories but nothing from ID1. It looks like the problem is more in the database it self. Because on a product page i use `{categories}<li><a href="{path=products/index}">{category_name}</a></li>{/categories}` and then i get the category where the product is in. So they are there. Maybe any idea?

Comment: Could you add the revised version of the {exp:channel:categories} code that still won't work for you? If the {categories} tag works within the channel entries tag, that suggests that everything is being stored correctly in the database. You could also try admin > system admin > output & debugging > set display output profiler to yes.

Comment: If you think the db is a factor, you could try admin I was unable to update my last comment, but the output profiler will show all the database queries being run, and if you find the one related to the channel categories tag, you can run it against the database yourself and review the results.
But posting more of the code you are using will help. As well as the exp:channel:categories tag, could you post the opening exp:channel:entries tag that is working for you on the product page?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, because i run this site on a localhost on work, i will post the code and test the debugging tomorrow morning.

Comment: Tidy - maybe this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddyfever/qTQrx/)  helps you to understand whats going on. Would you like have some more debug information?

Comment: You need to add channel="producten" whenever you use the channel categories tag. Also, can you try this code and report the output: {exp:channel:categories channel="producten" status="not closed" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
    {category_id} {category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories} and in your channel entries tag can you report the output of {categories}<li><a href="{path=products/index}">{category_name} *{category_id}*</a></li>{/categories}

Comment: And another try http://jsfiddle.net/eddyfever/WSqCL/1/ . Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry eddy at this stage I can't fathom how this could be happening. Hopefully someone else can help or if you still have your free ellislab support trial available you could go that route. Could even be a bug of some sort - have you checked the bug tracker?

Comment: Hi Tidy, thank you for your time. I also have no idea what was going on. This morning, i made a export from all entries and imported them with datagrab, i made a new category group and let datagrab do the rest. Besides a bit more work of sorting entries en categories everything works now. Again thank you for your time and we maybe never know what it was.